# Google "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" between UK and IE sites with same content meant for different audiences

Tags: google, duplicate-content, canonical-url, hreflang, country-specific

We have an `/ie` and `/uk` variation of our site.

`/ie` uses € and `/uk` £'s, both are in English.  Both sites are submitted to google as we want the IE site to return in googole.ie and UK site to return in google.co.uk

We have self pointing canonicals on each site and use href lang between the two sites. the UK site also is set as the default href lang site.

However we are seeing google crawl both sites and select either the IE or the UK URL to index for a page, not both sites as we intended.

We differentiate the HTML title and meta descriptions per site too.

I have had sites set-up like this in the past (UK US sites that time) and it has indexed both and return the correct site in the relevant version of google

However on this site we have issues between the IE and UK site.

Any ideas/advice would be great

We will begin looking at differentiating content further, but don't want have to re-write all copy unless 100% necessary

Comment: Have you added the sub-directories separately to Google Search Console and set the geographic targeting for each?